# Generate all possible distributions of numbers among baskets

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinatorics

There're 8 numbers (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,) and 5 baskets.
How can I generate all possible distributions of numbers among baskets? I saw cases about apples in basket but this case is not the same: apples - just some amount, while here each number is uniq.

I found greate package Combinatorics by Adrian Akison, but it's not clear how to use it in my case...

Even advice on how to use package logic would be helpful. Example of expected output:

- 0|0|0|0|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
- 0|0|0|1|2,3,4,5,6,7,8
- 0|0|0|2|1,3,4,5,6,7,8
- 0|0|0|3|1,2,4,5,6,7,8
- 0|0|0|4|1,2,3,5,6,7,8
- 0|0|0|5|1,2,3,4,6,7,8
- 0|0|0|6|1,2,3,4,5,7,8

Answer (score 1):

So for each number we should come up with a basket it belongs:

```
   12345678 
   --------
   00000000 <- all in basket #0
   00000001 <- all in basket #0, except number 8 which is in basket #1
   ...
   00000004 <- all in basket #0, except number 8 which is in basket #4
   00000010 <- all in basket #0, except number 7 which is in basket #1
   00000011 <- all in basket #0, except numbers 7 and 8 which are in basket #1
   ...
   44444444 <- all in basket #4
```

So far so good we have `5^8 == 390625` possibilities. Here they are:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<int[]> SolveMe(int numbers, int baskets) {
  int[] solution = new int[numbers];

  do {
     yield return solution.ToArray();

     for (int i = solution.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
       if (solution[i] == baskets - 1) 
         solution[i] = 0;
       else {
         solution[i] += 1;

         break;  
       }
  }
  while (solution.Any(item => item != 0));
}
```

Let's have a look:

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
  SolveMe(8, 5).Select(solution => string.Join(", ", solution)));

Console.Write(result);
```

Output: (for each number we get the basket it belongs)

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
...
1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3
1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4
...
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
```

If you want to look at baskets:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Baskets(int numbers, int baskets) {
  List<int>[] line = Enumerable
    .Range(0, baskets)
    .Select(_ => new List<int>())
    .ToArray();

  foreach (int[] solution in SolveMe(numbers, baskets)) {
    foreach (var item in line)
      item.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < solution.Length; ++i)
      line[solution[i]].Add(i + 1);

    yield return string.Join(" | ", line.Select(item => string.Join(", ", item)));
  }
}
```

Have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Baskets(8, 5)));
```

Output: (for each basket we have its contain)

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 |  |  |  | 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 | 8 |  |  | 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 |  | 8 |  | 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 |  |  | 8 | 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 |  |  |  | 8
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 | 7 |  |  | 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 | 7, 8 |  |  | 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 | 7 | 8 |  | 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 | 7 |  | 8 | 
...
7 | 5, 6, 8 | 1, 2 |  | 3, 4
7 | 5, 6 | 1, 2, 8 |  | 3, 4
7 | 5, 6 | 1, 2 | 8 | 3, 4
...
 |  |  | 8 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
 |  |  |  | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Comment: About possible variants - I got 390625 lines. Each line - one case. Started from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8|0|0|0|0 and ended with 0|0|0|0|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

Comment: @Common Work: I'm sorry for the typo: it should be `5^8 == 390625`

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer

```
using Combinatorics.Collections;

var P2 = new Permutations<char>(inputSet, GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition);
var allP = new List<string>();
foreach (var p in P2)
{
    var line1 = string.Join(",", p);
    var arr = line1.Split("|").ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].EndsWith(','))
            arr[i] = arr[i][..^1];
        if (arr[i].StartsWith(','))
            arr[i] = arr[i].Substring(1);
        if (arr[i] == "")
            arr[i] = "0";
        var tmp = arr[i].Split(',').ToList();
        if (tmp.Count > 1)
        {
            var intL = tmp.Select(x => Convert.ToInt16(x)).ToList();
            intL.Sort();
            arr[i] = string.Join(",", intL);
        }
    }

    var line2 = string.Join("|", arr);
    allP.Add(line2);
}
allP = allP.Distinct().ToList();
```

There're 390625 variants.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Combinatorics.Collections;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        int numBaskets = 5;
        var baskets = Enumerable.Repeat(0, numBaskets).ToList();

        var combinations = new Combinations<int>(numbers, numBaskets, GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition);

        foreach (var combination in combinations)
        {
            var currBaskets = new List<List<int>>(numBaskets);
            for (int i = 0; i < numBaskets; i++)
            {
                currBaskets.Add(new List<int>());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numBaskets; i++)
            {
                currBaskets[i].Add(combination[i]);
                baskets[i] = 1;
            }

            var remainingNumbers = numbers.Except(combination);

            foreach (var number in remainingNumbers)
            {
                var minIndex = baskets.IndexOf(baskets.Min());
                currBaskets[minIndex].Add(number);
                baskets[minIndex]++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", baskets) + "|" + string.Join(",", currBaskets.Select(b => string.Join(",", b))));
            baskets = Enumerable.Repeat(0, numBaskets).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it first create all combination and then  iterates  through each combination and distributes the numbers among the baskets

Comment: I did almost the same but with string and Permutations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).